# OSX : QNetworkProxyFactory::systemProxyForQuery is not able to find proxy on MAC but works fine in windows7

Tags: c++, macos, qt, networking, proxy

From QT i am trying to find out the proxy details. The below code works fine in windows7 but not working in MAC OSX 10.7,10.6. The retuned proxy type is coming as "NoProxy". I could see that the traffic from browsers safari/Chrome are going through proxy but not sure why QT is not able to find out. Please find attached proxy configuration image.

```
⁃   QNetworkProxyFactory::setUseSystemConfiguration(true);
⁃   
⁃       QNetworkProxyQuery npq(QUrl("https://www.google.com/"));
⁃           foreach (QNetworkProxy proxy, QNetworkProxyFactory::systemProxyForQuery(npq)) {
⁃               Log("Main", L">> proxy %ls, port %d type %d", proxy.hostName().toStdWString().c_str(),proxy.port(),proxy.type());
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded QT from 4.8.2 to 4.8.5 by compiling with System Proxies flag then it is working.